# Theano: Convolving every channel of tensor A with every channel of tensor B

Tags: python, deep-learning, theano, conv-neural-network, convolution

I have two 4D tensors of form: `(1, num_channels, r, c)`.

I'm assuming mini-batches of 1 here, and num_channels_a != num_channels_b

I would like to convolve every channel of tensor A with every channel of tensor B and collect the results as:
result = (num_channels_a, num_channel_b, result_r, result_c)

In plain old python this is straight forward:

```
result = np.zeros((tensorA.shape[1], tensorB.shape[1], result_shape_r, result_shape_c))
for channelA in xrange(0, tensorA.shape[1]):
    for channelB in xrange(0, tensorB.shape[1]):
        result[channelA, channelB] = scipy.signal.convolve2d(tensorA[0][channelA], tensorB[0][channelB], mode='valid')
```

This is, obviously, really slow and inefficient. It really should be a prime candidate for parallelizing as each channel combination's convolution is independent of any other channel combination.

I have tried implementing a Theano based function using theano.tensor.nnet.conv2d. This theano function assumes its inputs of the form: `(batch size, input channels, input rows, input columns)` convolved with `(output channels, input channels, filter rows, filter columns)`

Obviously the shapes correspond on "input channels" and is a common convolutional approach in neural nets, convolving the input data with a set of filters that match the same channel depth as the input data. This is not exactly what im trying to achieve.

I have tried using th.scan to loop over B's channels, then replicate this channels [r,c] vals a_num_channels times to do the convolution with tensor A, but this was not correct.

For example, my tensors could be of shape A(1, 40, 19, 19) and B(1, 100, 10, 10). In this instance I'd want to end up with a result of (40, 100, 10, 10)

Any ideas of how I might be able to accomplish what I'm describing above in a Theano function?

Comment: This would be do-able by using `theano.tensor.signal.conv.conv2d(tensorA[0], tensorB[0])` but unfortunately  `theano.tensor.signal.conv.conv2d` does not work on a GPU back end...